# Remove a specific xml node with namespace using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xml.modify

Trying to `remove xml` nodes using `groovy`. Here want to remove `requiredByDate` element, which is present multiple times and has namcespace with a prefix.

Looked at many examples available on the net, and stackover as well. Some of them are close. If there is no namespace for that xml element, then getting the desired output.

Problem is that the **xml element has namespace** and not able to achieve the intended out.

**Here is the groovy script that I am trying:**

```groovy
import groovy.xml.*
def x='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://www.example/test/commontypes" xmlns:ord="http://www.example/test/orderservice" xmlns:ord1="http://www.example/test/order">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
         <ord:orderRequest>
            <ord1:orderRef>${#TestCase#ORDERREF}</ord1:orderRef>
            <ord1:header>
               <ord1:description>user test</ord1:description>
               <ord1:customerID></ord1:customerID>
               <ord1:requiredByDate>2010-02-02T12:00:00-07:00</ord1:requiredByDate>               
            </ord1:header>
            <ord1:line>
               <ord1:lineNumber>1</ord1:lineNumber>
               <ord1:actionMode>mode1</ord1:actionMode>
               <ord1:requiredByDate>2010-02-02T12:00:00-07:00</ord1:requiredByDate>
            </ord1:line>
            <ord1:line>
               <ord1:lineNumber>2</ord1:lineNumber>
               <ord1:action>userAction</ord1:action>
               <ord1:requiredByDate>2010-02-02T12:00:00-07:00</ord1:requiredByDate>
            </ord1:line>
         </ord:orderRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''
def xml=new XmlParser().parseText(x)
def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'requiredByDate' }
nodes.each{it.parent().remove(it)}
XmlUtil.serialize(xml).toString()
```

The output comes the same as input i.e., does not remove `requiredByDate` elements(present 3 times in the xml)

If I hard code with namespace i.e., `'ord1:requiredByDate'`, then desired output comes. Referring `xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'ord1:requiredByDate' }` here.

However, I do not know what prefix comes in the xml during runtime. Hence, cannot use the hardcoded prefix in `findAll` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node with a namespace return a `QName` for his `name()` method. You can access the "local" name of the node, without the namespace, with the method `QName.getLocalPart()`

Try this:

```
def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name().localPart == 'requiredByDate' }
```

See [QName](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/QName.html)

Or the javadoc for [Node](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html):

> Typically the name is a String and a value is either a String or a
>   List of other Nodes, though the types are extensible to provide a
>   flexible structure, e.g. **you could use a QName as the name which
>   includes a namespace URI and a local name**.